# How does Jenkins Artifactory Plugin communicates resolver credentials to Gradle?

Tags: jenkins, gradle, artifactory

Using the Jenkins Artifactory Plugin and Gradle, I am able to deploy to my Artifactory instance successfully.  However, I have not been able to use the credentials entered into Jenkins configuration to resolve the artifact from the same repository.

Here is the `build.gradle`, adopted right from Artifactory's "Generate Build Script" feature in Artifactory.

```
apply plugin: 'java'

sourceCompatibility = 1.5
version = '1.0'
buildscript {
    repositories {
        maven {
            url 'http://artifactory.myorg.com:8081/artifactory/plugins-release'
            credentials {
                username = "${artifactory_user}"
                password = "${artifactory_password}"
            }
        }

    }
    dependencies {
        //Check for the latest version here: http://plugins.gradle.org/plugin/com.jfrog.artifactory
        classpath "org.jfrog.buildinfo:build-info-extractor-gradle:3.0.3"
    }
}

allprojects {
    apply plugin: "com.jfrog.artifactory"
}

artifactory {
    contextUrl = "${artifactory_contextUrl}"   //The base Artifactory URL if not overridden by the publisher/resolver
    publish {
        repository {
            repoKey = 'libs-release-local'
            username = "${artifactory_user}"
            password = "${artifactory_password}"
            maven = true

        }
    }
    resolve {
        repository {
            repoKey = 'libs-release'
            username = "${artifactory_user}"
            password = "${artifactory_password}"
            maven = true

        }
    }
}


dependencies {
    compile group: "com.myorg", name: "internal-library", version: '1.0'

    testCompile group: 'junit', name: 'junit', version: '4.11'
}
```

Job configuration on Jenkins: 
[image: Job configuration]

Jenkins Artifactory plugin configuration:
[image]

Error:

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Build file '/var/lib/jenkins/jobs/deleteme/workspace/build.gradle' line: 10

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating root project 'untitled2'.
> Could not find property 'artifactory_user' on Credentials [username: null].
```

Locally, resolving artifacts works (`artifactory_user` etc are resolved, because I configured them in my local `~/.gradle/gradle.properties`).  However, builds fail, because `artifactory_user` is not defined.  Of course, I can configure a `gradle.properties` for Jenkins to use (and this works), however how is this *supposed* to work? It appears the Jenkins Artifactory Plugin Gradle integration is supposed to somehow communicate resolver credentials.  Is there a way to do this without replicating the credentials in two places on Jenkins?

Answer (score 3):

**tl;dr** `username = "${project.getProperty('artifactory.publish.username')}"`

> Note: I haven't tested this on a Jenkins machine yet

The Jenkins artifactory plugin's gradle integration appears to do two things

- Inject the artifactory configuration using a [gradle init script]
- Provide build and artifactory configuration information

Both involve writing files to a temporary folder (i.e. `/tmp` on linux). If you have access to your build server you will probably have a lot of `buildInfo\d{19}.properties` and `init-artifactory\d{19}gradle` files in your temp folder.

Looking inside one of these buildInfo files reveals the resolve and publish credentials are stored in `artifactory.resolve.username` and `artifactory.publish.username`, respectively.

Trying to setting and trying to use `${artifactory.publish.username}` directly doesn't work on my local machine; I assume it has to do with gradle trying to access the property before it is set. But the `project.getProperty` method works.

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        maven {
            url 'http://artifactory.myorg.com:8081/artifactory/plugins-release'
            credentials {
                username = "${project.getProperty('artifactory.resolve.username')}"
                password = "${project.getProperty('artifactory.resolve.password')}"
            }
        }
    }
}

artifactory {
    publish {
        contextUrl = "${project.getProperty('artifactory.publish.contextUrl')}"
        repository {
            repoKey = 'libs-release-local'
            username = "${project.getProperty('artifactory.publish.username')}"
            password = "${project.getProperty('artifactory.publish.password')}"
            maven = true

        }
    }
    resolve {
        repository {
            contextUrl = "${project.getProperty('artifactory.resolve.contextUrl')}"
            repoKey = 'libs-release'
            username = "${project.getProperty('artifactory.resolve.username')}"
            password = "${project.getProperty('artifactory.resolve.password')}"
            maven = true

        }
    }
}
```

You will have to update your local `~/.gradle/gradle.properties` accordingly

```
artifactory.publish.contextUrl=<artifactory-url>
artifactory.publish.username=<username>
artifactory.publish.password=<password>
artifactory.resolve.contextUrl=<artifactory-url>
artifactory.resolve.username=<username>
artifactory.resolve.password=<password>
```

Comment: Great info and observations ... unfortunately it doesn't work on Jenkins.  The buildinfo file you mentioned contains the _output_ of artifactory "buildinfo" task, which then gets uploaded to artifactory.  Those property names do not appear to be available during the build tasks, still not sure yet where or how they get injected. Further research code be done, looking at https://github.com/JFrogDev/build-info, https://github.com/JFrogDev/jenkins-artifactory-plugin and printlns in the build script. For now the workaround to just set `~jenkins/.gradle/gradle.properties` manually is working fine.

Comment: Correction to my last comment, the buildInfo does _read in_ properties.  In fact, you can simply omit specifying `username` and `password` in the build.info for the `publish` and `resolve`, setting `gradle.properties` as you mention, and this works.  The only thing remaining is the plugins repo in the buildscript section, and there appears to be a catch22 here with the current implementation, the properties are set by the buildInfo plugin, but the properties are needed to load the buildinfo plugin.

Answer (score 1):

I am also banging my head against the wall with this one...I tried all the combinations myself and the only one that seems to be working is adding the gradle.properties to the jenkins server.

Finally I ended up not using the artifactory gradle plugin from jenkins alltogether.R ather add it to the build.gradle and simply call artifactoryPublish from Jenkins Server gradle plugin.